# How do you drop a header from a Pandas Dataframe formed by Scraping a Table using Beautifulsoup? (Python)

Tags: python, html, pandas, dataframe, beautifulsoup

I scraped a table from pro-football-reference and created a Dataframe but seem to be running into an issue due to the need to convert the html to a string.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
import pandas as pd
rb_r = requests.get('https://www.pro-football-reference.com/years/2021/rushing.htm')
rb_webpage = bs(rb_r.content, features='lxml')
rb_table = rb_webpage.find('table', attrs={'id': 'rushing'})
rb_df = pd.read_html(str(rb_table))[0]
print(rb_df.head().to_string())
```

Output:

```
  Unnamed: 0_level_0 Unnamed: 1_level_0 Unnamed: 2_level_0 Unnamed: 3_level_0 Unnamed: 4_level_0 Games     Rushing                                Unnamed: 14_level_0
                  Rk             Player                 Tm                Age                Pos     G  GS     Att   Yds  TD   1D Lng  Y/A    Y/G                 Fmb
0                  1  Jonathan Taylor*+                IND                 22                 RB    17  17     332  1811  18  107  83  5.5  106.5                   4
1                  2      Najee Harris*                PIT                 23                 RB    17  17     307  1200   7   62  37  3.9   70.6                   0
2                  3         Joe Mixon*                CIN                 25                 RB    16  16     292  1205  13   60  32  4.1   75.3                   2
3                  4     Antonio Gibson                WAS                 23                 RB    16  14     258  1037   7   65  27  4.0   64.8                   6
4                  5       Dalvin Cook*                MIN                 26                 RB    13  13     249  1159   6   57  66  4.7   89.2
```

I'm trying to remove the "Unnamed: 0_level_0..." header but everything I try hasn't worked. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're near to your goal, just add the header parameter to `pandas.read_html()` to select the correct one:

```
pd.read_html(str(rb_table), header=1)[0]
```

#### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
import pandas as pd
rb_r = requests.get('https://www.pro-football-reference.com/years/2021/rushing.htm')
rb_webpage = bs(rb_r.content, features='lxml')
rb_table = rb_webpage.find('table', attrs={'id': 'rushing'})
rb_df = pd.read_html(str(rb_table), header=1)[0]
print(rb_df.head().to_string())
```

#### Output

|  | Rk | Player | Tm | Age | Pos | G | GS | Att | Yds | TD | 1D | Lng | Y/A | Y/G | Fmb |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | Jonathan Taylor*+ | IND | 22 | RB | 17 | 17 | 332 | 1811 | 18 | 107 | 83 | 5.5 | 106.5 | 4 |
| 1 | 2 | Najee Harris* | PIT | 23 | RB | 17 | 17 | 307 | 1200 | 7 | 62 | 37 | 3.9 | 70.6 | 0 |
| 2 | 3 | Joe Mixon* | CIN | 25 | RB | 16 | 16 | 292 | 1205 | 13 | 60 | 32 | 4.1 | 75.3 | 2 |
| 3 | 4 | Antonio Gibson | WAS | 23 | RB | 16 | 14 | 258 | 1037 | 7 | 65 | 27 | 4 | 64.8 | 6 |
| 4 | 5 | Dalvin Cook* | MIN | 26 | RB | 13 | 13 | 249 | 1159 | 6 | 57 | 66 | 4.7 | 89.2 | 3 |

Comment: Wow, apparently I kept placing header=1 inside of the string parentheses which caused the error I was running into. Thank you!